# How do I use DataAnnotations on Radio Types?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, radio-button, data-annotations

I'm trying to make a form but I have 2 radio buttons which is a required choice if the user wants to complete the registration, but if he/she doesn't select anything, the `[Required]` DataAnnotation is not working here for some reason.

```
[Required]
public int UserType { get; set; }
```

How do I make the form return false with data annotations?

EDIT:

I've changed the model to

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please select an option")]
public int UserType { get; set; }
```

My view is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Registrationform", "Members", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "wizardform" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserType)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UserType, "1", new { @id = "vip_radio"})
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UserType, "2", new { @id = "normal_radio"})
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

when I press submit, the form returns with no errors (it submitted the form) even when I haven't clicked on any of the radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I have used like this

Metadata

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select usertype")]
    [Display(Name = "User type")]
    public string Usertype{ get; set; }
```

In view

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Usertype, "admin", new { id = "admin" })
 @Html.Label("admin", "admin", new { style = "padding-right:20px" })
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Usertype, "employee", new { id = "employee"})
 @Html.Label("employee", "employee", new { style = "padding-right:20px" })
```

works fine for me!

Comment: I've edited my question, the form stills proceeds normally even after I added the annotations in the model like you did.

Comment: I think u must use 'string' instead of 'int' ,it will work. And have u added the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js? for client side validation

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me with below code

```
$("#MyCheckBox").click(function(){ 
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $("#vip_radio").rules("add","required")
  } else {
      $("#normal_radio").rules("remove","required")
  }
});
```